# How to restrict the users on Thomson internet

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a Thomson TG585 v8 as my internet provider, but our neighbors keep hacking my WiFi. I don't know who to stop them. So how can I restrict the users? Can't I only allow my family members and friends (Using IP address)? I looked on the control panel but can't find a way. Any help? Or is their any external tool? This is really grinding my gears because I pay double and my internet is so slow. Thanks

Comment: Use WPA2 with AES. Choose a password that cannot be easily guessed.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I have done this. But I need a way to restrict users

Comment: Why do you think that? That's almost certainly not true. WPA2/AES with an unguessable password is sufficient, and most of the other techniques (like MAC filtering) are snake oil. (Make sure someone isn't sharing your WiFi credentials using Windows 10 sharing.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would allow users based on their MAC address (hard coded address on the physical network adapter) and not their IP Address.

Looking at a [manual](https://www.ote.gr/documents/10280/652016/TG585_SetupUserGuide_en_v8.pdf/0878a24f-0922-408c-bd51-fff55a07f53a) for your Thompson it doesn't look like they support MAC address filtering.

Easiest solution would be to change your wifi password on a regular basis.  Be sure and use a complex password.  [Tips for Complex Passwords](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/tips-for-creating-a-strong-password)

Now it's up to you on how often you change your password.

Other option would be to replace the Thompson DSL Modem/Router with a DSL Modem/Router that supports MAC-Address Filtering.  Then you would setup only specific devices that can connect.  If you have friends over you'll have to add their MAC address of the device they want to connect.

I would talk to your ISP about what type of DSL Modem you would need.  They might even have a newer model that supports MAC Address Filtering.  Worst case you buy a new one that will help keep the freeloaders off your network.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well you gave some info about the password but not about restricting users. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: I did mention that to restrict users you would need to do MAC Address filtering.  Which is not an option on your Thompson device.  Restricting users by IP address wouldn't work, as the user could just get another IP address.  To restrict users in your environment, you would need MAC Address filtering, which again isn't an option with your Thompson.  Not sure why the down vote.

Comment: Oh I didn't undertood that clearly. Thanks I will try it.
Note: The down vote is not by me. I will put your answer as correct :) Thanks :)

Comment: The down vote because MAC filtering is snake oil. Without encryption, it's useless because MACs aren't authenticated and someone can observe the legal MACs. With encryption, it's useless because they can't send valid data anyway.